# Create Multipage TIFF with Commons-Imaging

Tags: java, image, tiff

Im trying to check how to generate TIFF using JAVA libraries. I checked JAI, but it requires native libs that I can't use in my project (it must be platform-independent).

I saw a great library, Apache Commons Imaging that generates successfully TIFF, I tried and ...its good.

But I didnt see any way to create TIFF with several pages.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [icafe](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe/) Java library (disclaimer: I am the author of this library). No dependency on any native stuff. Look at the [wiki](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe/wiki) page for item **Create multipage TIFF image** for example. You can also control the color type and compression method for different pages. Dithering can be set through parameters in case color quantization is required such as saving images to black and white using CCITT group3/group4 compression. The resulting multipage image from the wiki page can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g4d2w6ipacf1rnf/piggie.tif).

Comment: I tried to use your library but encountered some wired problem, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973354/converting-pdf-to-multipage-tiff-group-4

Comment: This problem is fixed.